# Would it be possible to scrape data from Airbnb directly into a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a super simple Google Sheet dashboard comparing the prices at D+7 and D+30 in real-time of specific listings/rooms that are both on Airbnb and Booking.com.

On the Booking.com side, it was super easy : I just created a formula concatenating the URL with the check-in/check-out dates, number of guests and trip duration as parameters and using the =IMPORTXML function and the proper class, I was able to automatically retrieve the price.

It is more difficult on Airbnb, as the price is dynamic(see here: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/25961741). When I use what I think is the proper class, I get a "N/A Error, Imported content is empty" on Google Sheet.

I also tried using the Airbnb API with REGEX functions to extract the price, but the price set in the listing info is a default price, and does not reflect reality:

> "price":1160,"price_formatted":"$1160"

https://api.airbnb.com/v2/listings/25961741?client_id=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&_format=v1_legacy_for_p3&number_of_guests=1

Do you now if there are any other possible way to access this dynamic price and have it automatically parsed into a spreadsheet? It seems that the data I'm looking for in within meta tags on the HTML code and I don't know if it's possible to scrape it into Google sheet using =IMPORT functions.

Maybe with of a script ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious if you were unable to yank direct with the ABNB API; what if you tried to directly pull off the site's service? Have a look at this URL:

https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/explore_tabs?version=1.3.9&satori_version=1.0.7&_format=for_explore_search_web&experiences_per_grid=20&items_per_grid=18&guidebooks_per_grid=20&auto_ib=false&fetch_filters=true&has_zero_guest_treatment=false&is_guided_search=true&is_new_cards_experiment=true&luxury_pre_launch=false&query_understanding_enabled=true&show_groupings=true&supports_for_you_v3=true&timezone_offset=-240&client_session_id=8e7179a2-44ab-4cf3-8fb8-5cfcece2145d&metadata_only=false&is_standard_search=true&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&selected_tab_id=home_tab&checkin=2018-09-15&checkout=2018-09-27&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&click_referer=t%3ASEE_ALL%7Csid%3A61218f59-cb20-41c0-80a1-55c51dc4f521%7Cst%3ALANDING_PAGE_MARQUEE&allow_override%5B%5D=&price_min=16&federated_search_session_id=5a07b98f-78b2-4cf9-a671-cd229548aab3&screen_size=medium&query=Paris%2C%20France&_intents=p1&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&currency=USD&locale=en

This is a GET request to ABNB's live page search; now I don't know much about ABNB but I can see from the listings portion of the JSON feed it does have a few pricing factors that differ from the API results you provided; I'm not sure what you need to pull exactly but this may lead you in the right direction; check the 'Listings' array and see if there's something you can possibly use.

Keep in mind if you are looking to automate scraping this data you would want to generate new search sessions; but first you want to see if this is the type of data you're looking for.

Another option, Google CSE's API; I've pulled data in the page headers of sites as they appear in Google based on the Schema.org's tags; but this may be delayed data and it appears you need real-time; the best route would be reserach the above example or try to make sure of ABNB's natural API (they provide its functionality for a reason right?; there must be a way to get what you need).

Hope my answer helped lead you in the right direction!

Comment: Ilan, thanks a lot for your answer! I tried going through the search page as a first step, however the search is limited to 300 results and not all the listings I need appear in this selection. Moreover the prices are not the final prices as some fees are not included, which can be misleading. I did not know about Google CSE's API, but I will take a look at it. You're definitely right, I think the official API documentation could help me find what I need, I will try to access it. Thanks again!